# log4net log tail into operating memory

Tags: logging, log4net

If you have an web service which uses log4net as a logging subsystem, and you want to view the 'tail' of the log by one of the web service methods - how would you get the  log4net tail into operating memory without reading the log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: there is `MemoryAppender` class. Add it's initialization into your config and use it.

Long answer: [there is `LimitedMemoryAppender`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524201/548395), which implements events count limit. Then:

1. How to create it and add to appenders list:

```cs
logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("main");

var memoryAppender = new LimitedMemoryAppender ("MemoryAppender");
var l = (Logger)logger.Logger;
l.AddAppender (memoryAppender);
```

2. How to use it:

```cs
var memoryAppender = l.GetAppender("MemoryAppender") as MemoryAppender;
var events = memoryAppender.GetEvents().ToList ();
```

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your answer a bit to show how you configured and used the appender?